# How to fix an Unstable Build

Tags: ros, catkin, buildfarm, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those of us that don't speak build-farm, how do I make this build not unstable?

http://jenkins.ros.org/job/doc-hydro-navigation/26/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84296/how-to-fix-an-unstable-build/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-09-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the console output (http://jenkins.ros.org/job/doc-hydro-navigation/26/console), the only error I see is that it barfs when trying to send emails -- I'm guessing hersh@willowgarage.com (the maintainer email) is no longer valid?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-09-29**:
Thanks. I think this is what I'm looking for, although I have yet to check to see if this removes the unstable flag.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-29**:
Looks like it's not complaining about hersh, it's complaining about "a catkin package".

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-09-29**:
The line "Notification recipients: hersh@wDocumenting a catkin package" will extend the list of recipients and that might break the email notification plugin. The problem here seems to be that the output is mixed up (like stdout and stderr). I am pretty sure I filled a ticket about that some time ago but can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On that page there is a link called "Test Result". If you click on it you'll see that 1/1 tests failed. If you fixup that test it will likely be stable again. You can also get an unstable label if some warnings are detected, though I'm not sure how strict it is.

EDIT:

Well this is a doc job, so there is likely something else going on here (but the above still explains how/why a job is considered "unstable").

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-09-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd suggest running [rosdoc_lite](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdoc_lite) on your latest source in a catkin workspace.

See if that works, and what it says.

**EDIT**: to better duplicate the build farm doc environment, use a clean workspace that has not yet been built.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-09-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2